# How to create a list of times throughout a day that increment by 15 minutes?

Tags: python, datetime, time

In python I'd like to create a list of times (e.g. `[00:15:00, 00:30:00, ... , 23:30:00, 23:45:00]`) however whilst I can do this with dates I can't figure out how to do it with time exclusively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code creates and prints a list like you have asked:

```
out = []
for x in [str(x) for x in range(24)]:
    x = "0" + x if len(x) == 1 else x
    for i in [str(x) for x in range(60)][::15]:
        i = "0" + i if len(i) == 1 else i
        out.append("{}:{}:00".format(x, i))
print(out)
```

It's kind of bulky but it's a way to do it without imports.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say without knowing *what* you need the resulting list for, but if you just want strings, consider something like:

```
spacing = 15    # in minutes
lst = [str(i*datetime.timedelta(minutes=spacing)) for i in range(24*60//spacing)]
print(lst)
```

Note: This assumes (and requires) that the number of minutes in a day is evenly divisible by `spacing`, otherwise you'll get a close-but-not-correct list.

Output:

```
['0:00:00', '0:15:00', '0:30:00', '0:45:00', '1:00:00', '1:15:00', '1:30:00', 
 '1:45:00', '2:00:00', '2:15:00', '2:30:00', '2:45:00', '3:00:00', '3:15:00', 
 '3:30:00', '3:45:00', '4:00:00', '4:15:00', '4:30:00', '4:45:00', '5:00:00', 
 '5:15:00', '5:30:00', '5:45:00', '6:00:00', '6:15:00', '6:30:00', '6:45:00', 
 ...
 '21:00:00', '21:15:00', '21:30:00', '21:45:00', '22:00:00', '22:15:00', 
 '22:30:00', '22:45:00', '23:00:00', '23:15:00', '23:30:00', '23:45:00']
```

Comment: List comprehension can be harder to understand, but it is definitely more convenient and faster.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with list comprehension:

```
list_times = [f'{i:02d}:{j:02d}:00' for i in range(24) for j in range(0, 60, 15)]
print(list_times)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a range of integer values, each being the number of seconds since the start of the day.

```
def list_of_times(interval_in_seconds):
    return range(0, 86400, interval_in_seconds)
```

You can then adjust it to minutes by dividing it by 60 or formatting it using a Timedelta object

```
import datetime
datetime.timedelta(seconds=your_value_in_seconds)
```

A Timedelta object can be formatted as you wish